# Java required module can't be found

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I have a basic JavaFX project set up in IntelliJ:

[image]

The project uses Gradle for dependency management. The dependency that was added by my is javax.mail.api as you can see in the build.gradle file here:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.contoso'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = '18'
targetCompatibility = '18'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.contoso.portwatcher'
    mainClass = 'com.contoso.portwatcher.Application'
}

javafx {
    version = '18.0.1'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
    implementation group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

The iissue I have now is that when trying to execute to programm with the following run configuration:

[image]

I get the following exception:

[image]

The module-info.java file specifies the added dependency module:

```
module com.contoso.portwatcher {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javax.mail.api;


    opens com.contoso.portwatcher to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.contoso.portwatcher;
}
```

My question is why the module cannot be found?

Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: Just want to point out that setting those environment variables in IntelliJ should be unnecessary. You're using Gradle, and so IntelliJ should be able to infer everything from Gradle. You should also be delegating to Gradle to run your program (you've applied the `application` plugin; create a Gradle run configuration that simply executes the `run` task).

Comment: Please paste exceptions as text formatted as code and not screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mail API jar from [your dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api/1.6.2) doesn't define a `module-info.class`.

The [new Jakarta mail](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api/2.1.0) API does define the file. Migrate your usage of `javax.mail` to `jakarta.mail` packages and use the updated artifact, should work then.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to work. I did not know that javax.mail was deprecated.

Comment: @slowrabbit12 FYI, [many of the javax libraries used in jee had their package names changed to Jakarta](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee)